# How do I execute form action without redirect?

Tags: php, html, redirect, popup

UPDATE: iFrame solution worked:

```
<form action="script.php" **target="aniFrame"** method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Package:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<iframe name="aniFrame"></iframe>
```

I am executing a php script to send an email, but do not want the user to be redirected upon success.  How can I do this? (My script has a pop up box that comes up and says "Success!") Thank you!

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Package:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Adding my php code:

```
<?php
/**
* Simple example script using PHPMailer with exceptions enabled
* @package phpmailer
* @version $Id$
*/

require '../class.phpmailer.php';

try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body             = "Hello, World!";

    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 12;                    // set the SMTP server port
    $mail->Host       = "mail.blah.org"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "hello@bla.org";     // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = "pwd";            // SMTP server password

    //$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

    $mail->AddReplyTo("hi@hotmail.com","First Last");

    $mail->From       = "hi@hotmail.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "First Last";

    $to = "hi@gmail.com";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";

    header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Response"); //added this, works but no popup...
} 
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: AJAX is best option then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to have the server return a [`204 No Content` HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5).

Alternatively, set the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-target) of the form to an (i)frame.

Alternatively, use JavaScript to [capture the `submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for the form, [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), and make the HTTP request [using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: adding the 204 header worked to get it to not re-direct, but now my success popup box is not showing...any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to do something with the content of the response then you have to send some content in the response. Either use the first alternative or move your alert logic to the JS for the page with the form on it and use the second alternative.

Comment: Sorry...little confused, can you post some code so I can better understand both alternatives?  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Send an ajax call on submit button click. And on success of Ajax just show the pop up box saying Success..